# aging structure using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure like the following

```
TNO DATE        NETAMT  CHQ CASH    PARTY
---------------------------------------------
T1  01/04/2016  100     10  0       TEST1
T2  15/04/2016  50      0   0       TEST2
T3  18/04/2016  100     100 0       TEST3
```

Now I want to make a SQL query which will give me an aging report of which transactions are lying outstanding in which slabs.

I want to see the result in the following format

```
PARTY   0-3 DAYS    4-6 DAYS    7-15 DAYS
---------------------------------------------   
TEST1       0           0           90
TEST2       0           50          0
TEST3       0           0           0
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS

Comment: @ThomasG...its sql serevr 2012

Comment: Why is the first column named `PARTY` but the values in it are from the column `TNO`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...sorry...my bad...I have changed the structure please check

Comment: Seeing as your interval of days isn't uniform - you'll need a CASE to select the "age" of your line, and then you can use that as foundation for your result set. If the CASE then is dynamic, you'll need to build it dynamically as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  PARTY,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[DATE],GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 3  THEN (NETAMT - CHQ) ELSE 0 END) AS [0_3_DAYS],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[DATE],GETDATE()) BETWEEN 4 AND 6  THEN (NETAMT - CHQ) ELSE 0 END) AS [4_6_DAYS],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[DATE],GETDATE()) BETWEEN 7 AND 15 THEN (NETAMT - CHQ) ELSE 0 END) AS [7_15_DAYS],
FROM    TABLE1
GROUP BY PARTY
```

Comment: You may want to enclose your column alias in `[]` as you cannot start a column name with a number.

Comment: @abdul rasheed, thanks we are very close to the result...only thing left is that the result should come in a single row for each party...like if a party is having 2 different transactions in 2 different ages then the result should come in a single row...now with this query it is coming in 2 different rows

Comment: @user3305327 Enclose each `CASE` expression in `SUM` function and add `GROUP BY PARTY` at the end.

Comment: thanx @Felix Pamittan, query modified to get the sum for each party.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed No problem. A little explanation will help future visitors. =)

Comment: by changing this query am getting the following error...Column 'transact.PartyID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @sorry my bad i have made some mistake...now it working thanks...felix and abdul rasheed